# ASP.NET MVC intercepting route handling

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, routes

So I am facing this little problem. In my route config I have configured two routes. One default route, which handles `controller/action` request and one custom route which is basically `website.com/my_route` where `my_route` is received by some controller's action as an argument. the problem is that whenever I want to give that action a parameter which contains a '/' in it, the route handler resolves request to controller/action route config, so if looks like this `website.com/my_route/my_subroute`, you get what happens. the `my_routeController` is searched and of course it does not exist, now the number of '/' in url can be more than one as you see and I want to do such thing. if the appropriate controller with appropriate action does not exist I want this request to be handled but that one controller which's action will recieve `my_route/my_subroute` as an argument. What is the best practice in this situation. If need I can provide the route config.

Answer (score 0):

Try following way in your route.config

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "my_route",
    "my_subroute/x/y/z",
    new { controller = "controllername", action = "actionname" }
);


Let me know if this fixed your issue. :)
```

Comment: this did not help my issue. what I did was I made a subclass of MvcRouteHandler which checks if the controller ad action exist if not it redirect the current request to that one controller by changing the routevalues collection, but thanks anyways

Comment: and yeah I added one more config at the end which intercepts any every request if it cannot be mapped with any config above and mappes it to my desired controller, just by putting * at the beginning of template